# how to make an slash command with random answers?

Tags: javascript, random, discord.js

My code does not return an error but when I call it on discord, it does not responding.

```
import { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, CommandInteraction } from "discord.js";
import { SlashCommand } from "../types";

export const command: SlashCommand = {
  name: "dé",
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder().setName("dé").setDescription("DUEL"),

  execute: async (interaction) => {
    const liste = [
      "`1, tu as fait une réussite critique`",
      "`2, tu as fait une réussite moyenne`",
      "`3, tu as fait une réussite moyenne`",
      "`4, tu as fait une petite réussite`",
      "`5, tu as fait un petit échec`",
      "`6, tu as fait un echec critique`",
      "`7, quelque chose de drôle va arriver`",
      "`8, ça provoque l'effet d'un autre sort`",
    ];

    await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [new EmbedBuilder().setDescription(liste[Math.floor(Math.random() * liste.length)])],
    });
  },
};
```

I would like to make an slashcommand that answers one of these eight answers at random.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and checked myself, it works. So the problem is something else, didn't you forget to configure intents? Because it depends on whether the bot can write to the guild.

For example, you can set up the client in this way:

```
export const client = new Client({
intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping
]})
```

You also need to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/. There, click on the "Bot" tab and turn on all the checkboxes on Privileged Gateway Intents

P.S. Below I'm just proving that the code works. execute is a slash command

[image: Random Answers Code]

[image: Random Answer In Discord]